# Cannot connect to SSH with iptables firewall enabled

Tags: iptables, openvpn, iptables-persistent

I cannot seem to connect to my VPS even when enabling port 22 on my firewall. I have tried multiple iptables inputs to try and allow SSH to work. This is a debian 9 stretch system with iptables persistent installed. Below is the configuration (command form)

```
    # Allow all loopback (lo) traffic and reject anything
# to localhost that does not originate from lo.
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT ! -i lo -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow ping and ICMP error returns.
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state NEW --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# Allow SSH.
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED --sport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow UDP traffic on port 1194.
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED --sport 1194 -j ACCEPT

# Allow DNS resolution and limited HTTP/S on eth0.
# Necessary for updating the server and keeping time.
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED --sport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Allow traffic on the TUN interface.
iptables -A INPUT -i tuan0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j ACCEPT

# then reject them.
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT
iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j REJECT

COMMIT
```

Comment: skip the `--state ...` restrictions on the SSH rules, and (not relevant) correct the spelling of `tuan0`.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist Why should that cause any problem?

Comment: Add the output of `iptables -L INPUT -nv --line-numbers ; iptables -L OUTPUT -nv --line-numbers ; netstat --inet --inet6 -lnp` to your question. Can you connect locally i.e. `ssh localhost`?

Comment: You've included `tun0`. Have you got OpenVPN running too, and if so what is the contents of your routing table (`netstat -rn` or `ip route`)

Comment: I'm guessing that the rules end up dropping the response packets to the connection attempt.